# Disable keyboard input on TimePicker

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, timepicker

I want to disable keyboard input on TimePicker. Do you have an idea to solve this problem? Cause it's just annoying.

Thanks in advance!

By the way I tried this very popular solution `setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);`but it didn't work on my code.

Here is my code;

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public void selectTimeToDisplay(View view) {
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DisplayTimeFragment();
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}

public class DisplayTimeFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

    }
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        view.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);//doesnt work
        setSelectedTime(hourOfDay,minute);

    }
    public void setSelectedTime(int hourOfDay,int minute) {


         saat1.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/bolme1saat"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="selectTimeToDisplay"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bolme2saat"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't use the keyboard within this class, you can simply disable the keyboard

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

alternative can be forcing android to hide the keyboard

```
    // This works 100%

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I tried this before. Ridiculously the keyboard stil showing up.

Comment: Try forcing android to hide the keyboard programaticcaly

Comment: Write that where you placed the code for   view.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);//doesnt work

Comment: I just tried this and it worked ridiculously. `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: Thank you so much, mate! Sometimes this little details kills me sometimes :)

Comment: Awesome stuff, please accept the answer to help other people when viewing this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try android:focusable="false" and android:clickable="true" in xml.

Comment: I can't use focusable=false, cause there is onFocusChangeListener method for that edittext

Comment: Have you tried setting a style and point the theme of that layout? That worked for me when I wanted to temporarily stopping from popping up oncreate.